# SageMaker SkLearn - model is saving to the provided bucket, and not the complete provided path

Tags: amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am very new to SageMaker, and I am following the SkLearn example from this link:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.ipynb

I wanted to save my model in a specified S3, hence, I updated the estimator code as follow:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

FRAMEWORK_VERSION = "0.23-1"
script_path = "sklearn_abalone_featurizer.py"

sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    output_path = "s3://aws-prod01-sandbox/sklearnModel/model/"
)
```

However, the model is being saved to s3//aws-prod01-sandbox/sagemaker-scikit-learn-2021-07-08/source/sourcedir.tar.gz instead. It is not taking the key that I have provided in the estimator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

**I found the solution to this problem. Just in case anyone has the same issue, update the estimator as follow:

```
sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    output_path = "s3://aws-prod01-sandbox/sklearnModel/model/",
    code_location = "s3://aws-prod01-sandbox/sklearnModel/model/"
)
```

Comment: Just checking, shouldn't there be a `:` after s3 in your path?

Comment: @vmachan you are right, it was a typo when I am copying over manually. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: so did it solve your problem or are you still having the issue?

Comment: Nope, that was not the issue. Thank you for checking in! I found the code that was causing the issue. It is in the sagemaker.estimator.Framework; there is part of the logic that uses code_location to determine the output path.